# What is the best way to import data using insert statements into a table in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, import

I have exported a table from another db into an `.sql` file as insert statements.

The exported file has around 350k lines in it.

When i try to simply run them, I get a "not enough memory" error before the execution even starts.

How can import this file easily?

Thanks in advance,
Orkun

Comment: Would it be possible to export the data as is, instead of as a script and then use SQL Server's Import/Export wizard to import the data?

Comment: 'as is'? I export from an Oracle DB, and i could export to a csv too for example, if that helps

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually split sql file into smaller pieces. Use Notepad++ or some other editor capable to handle huge files.

Also, since you wrote that you have ONE table, you could try with utility or editor which can automatically split file into pieces of predefined size.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQLCMD utility.. search MICROSOFT documentation.. with that you just need to gives some parameters. One of them is file path.. no need to go through the pain of splitting and other jugglery..